# How do I display RVM's current Ruby and gemset in the Terminal prompt?

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm

I'm using [rvm-prompt](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/workflow/prompt/). It seems the interpreter, the version, the patchlevel, and the gemset should all displayed by default.

If I call the prompt, it accurately returns the current ruby and gemset:

```
$ rvm-prompt
ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails125
```

But my gemset isn't reflected in my prompt:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 MacBook:~ subpixel$
```

I tried calling the gemset explicitly in .bash_profile with:

```
PS1="\$(~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt i v p g) $PS1"
```

but it doesn't change the prompt.

Comment: Please don't use URL shortening services. There's no need.

Comment: You may need to put that in your `~/.bashrc` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [rvm-prompt](https://rvm.io/workflow/prompt), at the bottom of the page you'll find the following:

> ### ps1_functions
>
> Recently there has been a pair programming session that turned out a useful bit of prompt setting code. It now resides in contrib/ so you can require it in your profiles as follows after sourcing RVM itself.
>
> ```
> source "$rvm_path/contrib/ps1_functions"
> ```
>
> Immediately after that you can customize your prompt by adding the following line
>
> ```
> ps1_set
> ```
>
> There is an article and screen cast associated with this in the community resources section.

I copied the ps1_functions file, changed it to suit my needs and source that in my .bash_profile. Then I just have a line that calls

```
ps1_set
```

Now my prompt changes when I change gemsets

Answer (score 0):

You might have discovered a bug, because I see the same behavior. I'd recommend running it past RVM's author. You can find his email address by running `rvm -v`.